# Adding multiple markers in Google Maps V3 using Json

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to adapt my code with json in google maps. I tried looking at other threads of stackoverflow but did not help me.
How do I show multiple points on the map with the coordinates that are received by json? 
This code in firebug shows no errors and the map appears all blue.

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {  

var url = '/project/display/get_coordinates/';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

$.each(data, function(index, c) {   

//alert(c.fields['lat']+','+c.fields['lng']); result: -23.0522826,-43.32745712

//Map
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.fields['lat']+','+c.fields['lng']);  

//options
var myOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
streetViewControl: true
};   

//get the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

//marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: latlng,
  //title: {{i.display.codigo}}          
});

//infowindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: 'oi'
});

//click infowindow
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
});


});//close each

});//close getjson

}//close initialize
```

My response in Json:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "address.coordinates", "fields": {"lat": "-23.0522826", "lng": "-43.32745712"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "address.coordinates", "fields": {"lat": "-22.24569326", "lng": "-43.7028948"}}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: if the map shows up all blue, make sure it's not centered in the sea by zooming out...

another, more serious thing, you should not redeclare the map inside the callback function in $.each(...), but declare it in a global variable and attach markers to it

Comment: Hi!I'm trying to put many markers and infowindow on the map. The "blue" is related to some error in code, is not the ocean.Thanks!

Comment: The map is showing up like this: http://postimage.org/image/3phkv7l6v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have 1 real error here:**

```
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.fields['lat']+','+c.fields['lng']);
```

google.maps.LatLng expects 2 parameters(lat &lng) , but you provide 1(a string containing lat and lng, joined by a comma) . It has to be

```
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.fields['lat'],c.fields['lng']);
```

**But you also have a logical error:**

You overwrite the last map created on every each-loop

Create the map and the infoWindow outside of the $.each()

```
function initialize() 
{  
  var myOptions = 
      {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1,1) ,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: true
      }; 

   var url = '/project/display/get_coordinates/';


  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'oi'
                  });

    $.each(data, function(index, c) {   

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.fields['lat'],c.fields['lng']); 

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: latlng,
                      title:'pk:'+c.pk
                  });
      bounds.extend(latlng);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          infowindow.setContent('pk:'+c.pk);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });


});//close each
map.fitBounds(bounds);
});//close getjson

}//close initialize
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I make the change now in coordinates and the map is show with only 1 marker(the first marker dissapear and shows the second marker). But, if i put the creation of the map outside of $each() others parameters used by infowindow and marker are no reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set all you want to inside the loop when creating the marker or attaching the event, added an example above

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle! Works! Now the map has a center, multiple markers and infowindow and $each() populate the coordinates with json. Regards!